# Using Regular expression to search for a value but exlude that string from the results?

Tags: regex

This is prob really simple, I'm new to regular expressions but say I wanted to find the 2 numbers preceding some characters. i.e "12 qty"

So I'm using \d\d.qty to bring back the match "12 qty" but I want to exclude the word qty?

I have tried using \d\d.qty*([^qty]*) but it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm just trying to achieve this in regular expressions, I know it can be done easily in another programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [positive look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), depends on which language of course:

```
(\d\d)(?=\sqty)
```

Comment: Perfect, thats all I needed :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `(\d\d)(.qty)` so you get back

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12 qty
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  qty
        )

)
```

Now use second item of the array and you have, what you want